# What is this "tool" and how to disable it?

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm currently developing a program and I have this that shows up at the top of the window. I don't know what it is or how to remove it. I only have it in this specific program so I guess it's related to something I have done.

[image]

Comment: Tools|Options|Debugging uncheck Show runtime tools in application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is normal when running a XAML window in Debug. It let's you debug the window.
If you build in release mode, you'll see that this disappears.

If you want to turn it off, uncheck this option in the settings `Tools –> Options –> Debugging –> General –> Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML.`

Answer (score 0):

This is the XAML version of the HTML element inspector. By clicking the first button will bring you to the live visual tree window. Over there you can choose to toggle it on or off by clicking the "show runtime tool in application" button (first one on top menu bar)